# Не получается установить wine на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wine

Следовал инструкции с сайта https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu
Но столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)
                 Conflicts: wine
                 Conflicts: wine:i386
```

Я понял, что это из-за несовместимости каких-то версий. 
Версия такая:
**wine-4.0**
При попытке запустить программу выдаёт:

```
wine client error:0: version mismatch 547/571.
Your wineserver binary was not upgraded correctly,
or you have an older one somewhere in your PATH.
Or maybe the wrong wineserver is still running?
```

При вызове команды sudo apt --fix-broken install:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', which is also in package libwine-vanilla:i386 4.0-eter1ubuntu
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-wine (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wine/fonts/coue1255.fon', which is also in package libwine-vanilla:i386 4.0-eter1ubuntu
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo apt purge wine* libwine && sudo apt update` и дальше по инструкции

Comment: E: Unable to locate package 'winehq.key' - вот что выдаёт при вызове этой команды. При попытке добавить winehq.key как в инструкции пишет: File 'winehq.key' already there; not retrieving. Также при  попытке добавления репозитория sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main' *не находит Release file* , но приэтом при попытке зайти по ссылке, то скачивает Release key. Может необходимо просто добавить Realese.key куда-то?

Answer (score 1):

Доброе время суток. Сегодня сам столкнулся с подобной проблемой.

Для начала Вам необходимо удалить все старые версии, как написано в комментарии к вопросу.

sudo apt purge wine* libwine && sudo apt update

Сама ошибка установки связана с отсутствием пакета libfaudio0, он отсутствует в стандартном репозитории. Взять можно:
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/i386/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb

Установка через dpkg

После установки этого пакета следуйте инструкции с оф. сайта.
При необходимости сброшу ссылку на инструкцию, где описан весь процесс установки Wine 5.0 на Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если уменя процессор интелловский, то мне надо i386 устанавливать? Когда я устанавливал образ диска ОС там было md64.Может ли быть в этом проблема? Попытался установить оба установщика, выводит следующую ошибку:`Selecting previously unselected package libfaudio0:i386.
(Reading database ... 169107 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libfaudio0:i386 (19.07-0~bionic) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfaudio0:i386:
 libfaudio0:i386 depends on libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.8).`

Comment: amd64 - 64х-разрядная система. По инструкции установки Wine, одним из пунктов Вы добавляете поддержу 32-битной архитектуры.
Относительно ошибки, установите это зависимость вручную sudo apt-get install libsdl2

Comment: Перепробовал много разных вариантов с инета: не получается установить эту библиотеку. Может быть я установил "багнутую" версию убунты? Не понимаю как оперировать этими командами. Вы как-то писали, что поделитесь ссылкой, кажется, она мне нужна.  E: Unable to locate package libsdl2

Comment: Относительно установки libsdl2, устанавливаем командой
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0  Полную установку Wine, с добавлением репозитория с необходимыми библиотеками описал http://hh-pc.top/install-wine-ubuntu-18-04/ по этой инструкции установил на 5 ПК за последний мецяц